# Using optirun makes Acer Aspire 5755G laptop overheat

Tags: fan, bumblebee

Using `optirun` from the `bumblebee` package makes my laptop (Acer Aspire 5755G) overheat after some time while the fans don't seem to run using the highest performance yet.

Comment: Optirun is to just enable your grphics card. So it will produce heat. If the fans are not working as expected contact vendor your hardware check. Also clean up dirts

Answer (score 0):

Add [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) (if you don't have it already) to your system and update, reboot.